# "Your device is not compatible with this version" on Verizon Ellipsis 7" Android version 4.2.2

Tags: android, cordova

We have an Android app running on Cordova. It has already been published to Google Play and is already running on hundreds of devices. We just found out that users using Verizon's Ellipsis 7 Android version 4.2.2 cannot find the device on Google Play. When accessing the app directly using it's Google Play URL, it says that the device is not compatible with the version of the app.

From my research, the Ellipsis 7 has an unusual screen density for its size. Here is the contents of the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="[removed package name]"
          android:versionName="3.4.1" android:versionCode="73">

      <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true" 
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

                                <!-- all normal size screens -->
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

                                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="240" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="240" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="240" />
                                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="240" />


</compatible-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

      <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" android:required="false"/> -->

    <application
            android:debuggable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter></intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- ZXing activities -->
          <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
              <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="share_name">
              <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
              </intent-filter>           
          </activity>

    </application>


    <uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="11" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: No idea if this is right, but have you tried with xxhdpi?  And, if it "works with anything" why define what "anything" means with all those `screen` tags?